# The property 'Description' does not exist on type

Tags: 2013, list, rest

I am trying to save a list item via REST and sending following piece to SharePoint API:

```
        var updatedTaskInformations = {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
            },
            "Status": "Completed",
            "PercentComplete": 1,
            "Description": comment
        };
```

But I only receive this message:

> The property 'Description' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.TasksListItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

But the tpe exists and the Column `Description` does also exists.

Is this column read-only for REST API or is it just not visible to REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the internal name of column. In Tasks lists, the internal name is `Body`

Try it as below:

```
var updatedTaskInformations = {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
            },
            "Status": "Completed",
            "PercentComplete": 1,
            "Body": comment
        };
```

Comment: ooohhh, okay. That should be the answer. Thanks man!

Comment: Its ``Body`` in Tasks lists and I think ``Description`` in the IssueList. To find the internal info; you need to understand SharePoint so you know what to browse/look for with this great Chrome Browser Extension "SharePoint Insider" ► https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sharepoint-insider/gjckpigahcbffmeofjfedlffddhfidhj?hl=en (similar to tools like Bram de Jagers's SharePoint Client Browser and many others)

Answer (score 2):

I post this as a note to anyone who googles their way here. (Not enough rep to add a comment.)

If your custom List names, or the names of their custom fields contain spaces, SharePoint replaces them in the internal name with:

> _x0020_

To determine what the internal names are, paste the following into the address bar of your browser and use Ctrl-F to search the XML that is returned for your field's display name (change the bold, below, for your site's name, individual page, and for your list's display name):

**mySite**.com/sites/**myPage**/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('**My Custom List**')/Fields

> EG: "First Name" becomes "First_x0020_Name" when populating your JSON request

Hope this helps.

Edit: Fixed case issue.

Comment: Adding that column names over 32 characters will have their internal names truncated to 32 characters.

Comment: Also worth noting that it's actually \_x0020_ (case sensitive).